# JSON pivot table - able to access all values

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Is it possible to list all facilities from my JSON but still have be able to access use hotel information?  Currently it only works if I spit out the facilities only.

JSON

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "hotel_title": "Name of Hotel",
  "hotel_description": "10",
  "facilities": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "facility_name": "Foo",
      "facility_description": "Bar",
      "pivot": {
        "hotel_id": "1",
        "facility_id": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

CALL TO  JSON

```
$.getJSON("{{ url('api/facilitieslist')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 
                function(data) {
                        $('#facilities').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
                             $('#facilities').append('<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + value.id +'" name="facilities[]"> ' + value.name +'</div>');
                        });

                });
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. Could you provide an example of the HTML you want rendered for the JSON data you provided? You might also want to use a larger JSON example, with multiple facilities and/or multiple hotels, if that more accurately reflects the data you'll be retrieving from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the sample you posed will actually work (you are looping on data and not data.facilities and your attribute names are ambiguous and don't exist in the JSON object you posed), however, this example shows how to loop through your facilities and still access your hotel data (I *think* this is what you want):

```
var data = {
  "id": "1",
  "hotel_title": "Name of Hotel",
  "hotel_description": "10",
  "facilities": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "facility_name": "Foo",
      "facility_description": "Bar",
      "pivot": {
        "hotel_id": "1",
        "facility_id": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
};

$.each(data.facilities, function(key, value) { 
    console.log('<div>' + value.facility_name + ' - ' + data.hotel_title +'</div>');
});
```